# Created custom tiles, added tile bounds to leaflet but it's still trying to load tiles outside of boundaries

Tags: leaflet, tiles, tilemill

I created custom tiles in TileMill with latitude/longitude boundaries of:

```
-89.8235,43.3377,-89.5952,43.4741
```

I added those tiles into the map and set the tile layer's bounds attribute, but Leaflet still is giving me a lot of "Not Found" errors in the console.

Here's my code for adding the tiles:

```
{
    "parks boundaries": L.tileLayer('data/custom-tiles/boundaries/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
           bounds: [[43.3377,-89.8235],[43.4741,-89.5952]]
    }).setOpacity(0.4).addTo(map)
}
```

Here are some of the errors I'm getting:

```
GET http://localhost/cart575final/data/custom-tiles/boundaries/14/4105/5994.png 404 (Not Found) 
GET http://localhost/cart575final/data/custom-tiles/boundaries/14/4105/5995.png 404 (Not Found) 
GET http://localhost/cart575final/data/custom-tiles/boundaries/14/4105/5993.png 404 (Not Found)
```

Why is Leaflet still trying to fetch tiles that don't exist when the bounds of my tiles are clearly stated?

Comment: What's happening when you open http://localhost/cart575final/data/custom-tiles/boundaries/14/4105/5994.png in a web browser ?

Comment: Most likely Leaflet tried to load tiles because your boundaries were in the wrong place. In this case the tiles are not limited by the specified boundaries.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are asking the wrong question ...

Leaflet does the right thing: the tiles you see in your errors belong to your boundaries.

To be convinced of it, please have a look at this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FranceImage/4bghwrvw/) where your boundaries are shown as a rectangle.

You see that Leaflet only loads the tiles needed and that 14/4105/5993.png is shown

Comment: My boundaries are pulled directly from the Tilemill file used to create the tiles. Why would Tilemill incorrectly display the boundaries?